# Opening Lightning Combobox options upwards

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, selectlist, lightning-combobox

Since my dropdown is at the bottom of the page, if we try to select a value, it adds extra scrolling as select options open downwards.
Can we open it upwards instead of downwards, either using lightning Combobox or select options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [lightning-combobox specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/specification) lists the available attributes. What you're looking for is `dropdown-alignment`

> Specifies where the drop-down list is aligned with or anchored to the
> selection field. **By default the list is aligned with the selection
> field at the top left so the list opens down. Use bottom-left to make
> the selection field display at the bottom so the list opens above it**.
> Use auto to let the component determine where to open the list based
> on space available.

```html
<lightning-combobox
    ...
    dropdown-alignment="bottom-left"
    ...
>
</lightning-combobox>
```

Comment: My Bad, Didn't check the attributes properly and ended up trying something else. Thank you for pointing out the blunder I made.